# Question about gluons and the W-boson regarding Feynman diagrams

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, elementary-particles

My questions are:

1) Does a gluon always have no charge?

2) Is the W-boson always positive or negatively charged?

I thought these two statements were correct, but I came across an exercise that makes me doubt it. 
In the exercise I have to make a feynman diagram for the reaction :

u + $\bar{u}$  $\rightarrow$ d + $\bar{d}$

My two answers were d) and d) with a gluon instead. I thought b and c were not allowed. The $\bar{u}$ and $\bar{d}$ in b aren't electrically neutral together, which the gluon is. I had the same reasoning for c but instead the two are electrically neutral while the W-boson has a positive or negative charge. Am I thinking wrong?

[image]

Comment: Are these the four answers that the exercise deems correct?

Comment: Yes, they say these 4 are correct.

Comment: Where did this exercise come from?

Comment: Just homework exercises for university, or did you mean something else?

Comment: No, just wondering whether there's some textbook that has a major error.

Comment: Aah, do you mean my thought process is correct?